# Maven easyb plugin java heap space settings?

Tags: java, plugins, maven-2, heap-memory, easyb

I attempted to change my heap size for maven easyb plugin 
http://www.easyb.org/maven-easyb-plugin/. In my easyb test I added 
standard code to print the heap size using the code 
Runtime.getFreeMemory() and Runtime.getTotalMemory().

I tried setting the MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m and also set the 
maven opts in Maven surefire plugin. Now when I run the same class 
from the Junit I can see the getTotalMemory() displaying a number 
close 1Gig but the when the same classes are invoked from easyb plugin 
they do not reflect the memory size.

Shouldn't there be a way of passing JVM opts to maven easyb plugin 
when it runs these easyb tests? At the very minimum it should atleast 
pick up the MAVEN_OPTS settings from the environment.

Has someone bumped into problems like this? (A search on this group's 
archive does not reveal much)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m
```

Probably, MAVEN_OPTS is even not necessary. My guess is that MAVEN forks a new JVM inside to run easyb. And, probably, it's wise of MAVEN to separate it's own JVM settings from settings for JVM it runs.

Answer (score 0):

This is *Issue [77](http://code.google.com/p/easyb/issues/detail?id=77&q=memory&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Component): Enhancement: specify max memory for maven plugin* which is still "New" but has a patch (with tests) attached. So grab the sources, patch them and rebuild the plugin.